# .NET Core copy subfolders to output on build and publish

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have a `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` project and in the solution folder I have a `Lib` folder with subfolders which in turn have files, for example:

```
Lib
  sv
    myfile.dll
  de
    myfile.dll
```

I added the following to the `csproj`:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Lib\sv\**">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Lib\de\**">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

But the above is placing the subfolders and their files within the `Lib` folder in the output folder.

I need to have the following:

```
(OutputPath)
  sv
    myfile.dll
  de
    myfile.dll
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use  `Link` to change Output Path as follows, I also used `Visible` so that the changes don't appear in Solution Explorer:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Lib\sv\**">
        <Link>\sv\%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <Visible>false</Visible>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Lib\de\**">
        <Link>\de\%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <Visible>false</Visible>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, msbuild will reflect the folder structure of the included contents into the output path and this cannot be altered.

I think your only option is to manually fix the output folder to match what you want. On windows you could use

```
move bin\Debug\net5.0\Lib\sv bin\Debug\net5.0
move bin\Debug\net5.0\Lib\de bin\Debug\net5.0
```

There are many ways of automating this in your solution. One way is to use `Post Build Events` under `project properties -> Build -> Events`. It should add the following to your csproj

```
 <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
     <Exec Command="move bin\Debug\net5.0\Lib\sv bin\Debug\net5.0&#xD;&#xA;move bin\Debug\net5.0\Lib\de bin\Debug\net5.0" />
 </Target>
```